# How to generate entities from Doctrine PHP mapping using ClassMetadataBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity

I am trying to configure entities with [ClassMetadataBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/php-mapping.html#classmetadatabuilder), but I can't seem to find a way to generate entities from that class using

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities src
```

My example code is from the docs and looks like:

```
class User {

    private $id;
    private $name;

    public static function loadMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata) {
        $builder = new ClassMetadataBuilder($metadata);
        $builder->createField('id', 'integer')->isPrimaryKey()->generatedValue()->build();
        $builder->addField('name', 'string');
    }

}
```

When I use annotations based configuration I can generate entities just fine with the following **cli-config.php**:

```
$entitiesPath = array('src/Entity');
$isDevMode = $configuration->getValue('mode') === 'TEST';
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entitiesPath, $isDevMode);

$conn = $db->getConnectionDetails();
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

What metadata driver should I be using in configuration instead of `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration`? Or am I doing the PHP mapping entirely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up skipping the command line and used `EntityGenerator` in my PHP code.

```
//generator code
(new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator())->
    generate(array(MyMetadataLoader::loadMetadata()), "src/Entity");

//metadata loader
public static function loadMetadata() {
    $metadata = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata("Entity/User");
    $builder = new ClassMetadataBuilder($metadata);
    $builder->setTable('user');
    $builder->createField('id', 'integer')->isPrimaryKey()->generatedValue()->build();
    $builder->addField('name', 'string');
    return $builder->getClassMetadata();
}
```

And for creating tables

```
$em = MyEntityManagerLoader::loadEntityManager();
$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
$classes = array(
    MyMetadataLoader::loadMetadata()
);
$tool->createSchema($classes);
```